# Java read elements in string element by element

Tags: java, string, arraylist

Ok I'm having some problems reading elements from a string, I'm given some user inputted file and I read every line into an arraylist. Now I need to access each line and read these integers from it and set them to int variables. There will be multiple integers per line though see sample below. Can someone help with this?

```
1 5
1 4
2 3
3 1
10 13
100 203
etc...
```

So for the first line I want to do something like:

```
first line:
int i = string.element1 // 1
int j = string.element2 // 5

...etc...

last line:
int i = string.element1 // 100
int j = string.element2 // 203
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `split()` method to get `String`s and then convert them to `int` via `parseInt()`:

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
String string = "100 203";
String[] parts = string.split(" ");

i = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
j = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ArrayList<String> yourArray...; //this is your array list containing all lines from your file
for(String data : yourArray){
    String[] nums = data.split(" ");
    Integer num1 = Integer.parseInt(nums[0]);
    Integer num2 = Integer.parseInt(nums[1]);
}
```

Something like that?